# HTML Forms - Prewritten text

Tags: javascript, html, input

This may not be the best area for this question and if so I am sorry for that. However, I am trying to create a dead simple form that enters pre-written data into the fields when they hit a key. So example:

```
User Enters: Hello world, My name is...
```

But the input field will instead progressively write

```
Form: G'day, the weather is great today.
```

I've seen this done a few times but for some bloody reason I can't track down the tutorial for it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I would like it to basically be this [youtube](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CEoQtwIwAw&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V1iwqYDFCPw&ei=hr4qT8-3B_GuiQfKmpncDg&usg=AFQjCNFT3R0ZNTUFs8f-6LZomF49Qoszzw&sig2=tlNGcpHCrCA3w6U2KUq1MA)

Comment: Are you asking for some JavaScript that will appear to 'type' on the screen when the user hits a key? Kind of like http://uni.xkcd.com/

Comment: @Kerian You mean like a chatbot?

Comment: I'm trying my best sorry, basically when a user starts typing in a form instead of what they are writing to show up, pre-written data shows up instead

Comment: @Blowski is on the right track!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the jQuery tickertype plugin: http://www.hungry-media.com/code/jQuery/tickerType/